# Double click event on C3 chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, c3.js

I am using c3 chart and i need to show tool tip when i click on the bar and on double click something else.

There is the onclick even for c3

```
 data: {
              columns: [],
              onclick: function(d, i) {
                     //dosth
              },
}
```

Couldn't find any resources for double clicks.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
In my html

```
  <c3-chart config="MyChart"></c3-chart>

  $scope.MyChart= {
    data: {
          columns: [],       
          type: 'bar',
        }
}

      $scope.MyChart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.eventRect).on('dblclick', function (d) {
    var $$ = chart.internal;
    $$.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.circle).each(function (d) {
        if ($$.isWithinShape(this, d)) {
            // event handling
            alert(d.value);
        }
    });
})
```

Have two issue
1. i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
2. doubt this works for bar as its searching for circle to initiate double click

Answer (score 1):

## Attaching a Double Click Handler to a C3 Chart

Where `chart` is your chart object, you can do something like

```
chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.eventRect).on('dblclick', function (d) {
    var $$ = chart.internal;
    $$.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.circle).each(function (d) {
        if ($$.isWithinShape(this, d)) {
            // event handling
            alert(d.value);
        }
    });
})
```

This basically filters down to the event layer elements (that's where c3 delegates it's event handlers to) i.e. `..CLASS.eventRect` and attaches a double click handler.

On double clicking, we loop through all the points i.e. `..CLASS.circle` and check if the click is within that specific shape. If yes, we trigger the handler (`this` is the element and `d` is the attached data)

Note that all selectors are scoped to the chart element (`chart.internal.main`), so that it works correctly when there are multiple charts on the same page.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eo2kszt2/

Comment: You seem to be using a directive for c3. You might want to post that too.